# how to add multiple nodes in Firebase cloud Firestore using flutter

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding some information in `firebase` cloud `firestore` using flutter.Now i need to add some more detail against nodes. like here is i am adding data to cloud `firestore`.

```
void _addData(){
    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async{
      CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('task');
      await reference.add({
        "email"   : widget.email.toLowerCase(),
        "title"   : newtask,
        "members" : members,
        "note"    : note,
      });
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);   
  }
```

in this example i want to add some extra detail against the node `Member`.
 i want list of members against this. i am confused how to do that.

i want to add node against node like this using `FirebaseDatabase` here is the code.... `Firestore` dose not allow collection against collection like `firebaseDatabase`  child against child.

```
   return FirebaseDatabase.instance
              .reference()
              .child(USERS)
              .child(user.uid)
              .update(update

);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
DocumentReference messageRef = db
    .collection("rooms").document("roomA")
    .collection("messages").document("message1");
```